# rand() produces the same result on each function call (with srand(time(0))

Tags: c++, random

I have a member function of a class that is supposed to generate a random number in a range. To do so, I am using the rand() function. The function generates a random number like this:

```
    unsigned seed;
    seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    std::cout << "Random Number: "<< rand() << std::endl;
```

The function is called on two different objects. The result is:

```
Random Number: 1321638448
Random Number: 1321638448
```

This is consistent every-time I call it. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's very unusual to reseed the randomizer multiple times in a program - usually you do it once, up front, and then never touch it again. And `time` usually has the resolution of *one second*, so if you generate two random values this way in the same second, you'd expect to see this.

Comment: If i should only seed it once, should i do it in my main? I think I shouldn't do it in the class constructor since that will be called twice.

Comment: Just did the above and it worked! thank you!

Comment: John, you could do lazy initialisation in the constructor, something like `static bool first = true; if (first) { first = false; srand(time(nullptr)); }` but the `main` proposal is probably better since your class may not be the *only* thing using random numbers.

Comment: What platform are you running this on? It should work

Comment: if you tag it [c++] consider using something from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Converting my comment to an answer).

For most applications, you'll only really want to seed `rand` once in the course of running a program. Seeding it multiple times requires you to get different random seeds, and it's easy to mess that up.

In your case, the `time` function usually returns something with resolution on the level of seconds (though [this isn't actually required by the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t)). As a result, if you call `time` twice within the same second, you might get back the same value. That would explain why you're getting duplicate values: you're seeding the randomizer with the same value twice and then immediately querying it for a random number.

The best solution to this is to just seed the randomizer once. Typically, you'd do that in `main`.

If you really do want to seed the randomizer multiple times, make sure that you're doing so using a seed that is going to be pretty much random. Otherwise, you risk something like this happening.

Comment: On Linux you can read a value from `/dev/urandom` to get a better seed than `time`.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudorandom number generators basically have to pass a set of statistical tests to make sure they're "random enough" as a set of numbers. But of course, it's not actually random. Calling `srand(seed)` with some `seed` basically generates a set of numbers which, if passed through those tests, will seem "random enough".

By calling `srand(seed)` with the same `seed` multiple times, you're effectively generating the same set over and over again and getting the first value in it.

You call `srand(seed)` ONCE, and then you call `rand()` to get the next values in the random number set. Or you need to call `srand(seed)` with a different (random) seed each time.

If you're on linux, you can also use `/dev/urandom` to get a random number- the kernel has been taking signal/noise from the environment to generate "entropy" for it, supposedly making it even better than an algorithm psuedorandom number generator.

Comment: It is not the same seed every time. time(0) gives the current time as a 32bit or 64bit integral type

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but as the commenter above explains, calling time(0) in quick succession in-fact returns the same number.

Comment: Also, OP doesn't call srand(time(0)), OP calls srand(seed), where seed was set to time(0) at some point.

Answer (score 0):

`srand` function should be called only once in program(most cases, not all cases). If you want reseed, you should use different seed number. Because `rand()` function is pseudo-random number generator. In other words, `rand()` gives you a calculated number.

You can use much for powerful random number generating library after C++11. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: "`srand` function must be called only once in program." is too hard a statement and that renders it untrue. There are rare cases where reseeding the random number generator *is* required. Though I admit you are likely to go through a career in programming and never encounter one of these cases.

Comment: @user4581301 like the case of multi-thread? Oh, I don't even want to imagine that...

Comment: Note that the library at http://www.pcg-random.org/ provides the same interface as `<random>`, but is better in many ways.

Comment: You know what? I've never used `srand`/`rand` in a multithreaded program. Had to look it up to see if it's threadsafe after C++ 11.  Looks like it's not guaranteed. These days any case where you'd need to reseed, you're almost certainly using a better random number generator.