# Why does the random number generator not randomize numbers in the void function but does in the main function?

Tags: c++, random

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void coinToss();

int main()
{

cout << "How many times do you want to flip the coin?\n";
   
int choice;
   
cin >> choice;

   for (int i = 1 ; i <= choice; i++)
   {
       cout << "Rolling Dice # " << i << endl;
       coinToss();

   }
   return 0;
}

void coinToss()
{
   
unsigned seed = time(0);
   
srand(seed);

   int result;
   result = (rand() % (2 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
   if (result == 2)
       cout << "Tails\n";
   else
       cout << "Heads\n";
       cout << endl;
}
```

> When I do this it does not randomize the number and just gives the same number over and over. But if i  put "unsigned see = time(0); srand(seed);" in my main function it actually randomizes and gives out different numbers?

Comment: Do you know what `unsigned see = time(0); srand(seed);` does?

Comment: You're seeding with `srand` every time you call the function. Probably not enough time happens between consecutive function calls, so `seed` is always the same value.

Comment: You reset the generator with the same seed, so it produces the same sequence (of which you only use the first element).

Comment: Call `srand()` _exactly once_ in the _whole program._

Comment: @BessieTheCow I am not sure entirely because it is the only thing I learned from my textbook that shows how to randomly generate a number, so yeah I do not know if it does anything else beyond what randomly generating something.

Comment: @Justin if you do not mind, can you explain a little more in-depth why seed is always the same value or sequence when I call it in the void function?

Comment: This is why you don't copy code you don't understand. Those two lines of code take the current time accurate to a second, and uses that to set the internal state of the random number generator. If you put it inside your `coinToss` function, it will reset the state of the random number generator every time you generate a number. Since the time is only accurate to one second, your code will end up resetting the state of the random generator to the same thing every time you generate a new number, so the results are going to be the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rand() produces the same result on each function call (with srand(time(0))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750707/rand-produces-the-same-result-on-each-function-call-with-srandtime0)

Comment: @BessieTheCow Yeah, and I didn't mean to copy it i guess. This is the first time seeing more information about it rather than some lines of text stating its a random number generator. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Typically with linear-feedback random number generators, you initialize the randomizer once with a seed, then invoke rand() multiple times using that same seed. Each call to rand() would be saved, and used in the NEXT call to rand() - therefore self-mixing which creates "Random Looking" numbers - IE a pesudo-random-number-generator (PRNG)

```
          |--------|
          |  Seed  | Set Once
          |________|
              |
|--------|    v
| Rand() |----\ Mix with seed or last rand()
|________|    |
    ^         v
    |     |--------|
    \-----| Rand() |
          |________|
```

As mentioned, you are reseeding the randomiser (which resets it), then calling rand() EACH coinToss(). This will NOT allow the rand() to mix with previous calls to rand() (as you reset it), and therefore not produce random numbers. You have to also realize this is PESUDO random numbers, ie NOT real randomness, just random-looking.. So the code may do all sorts of dodgy stuff to produce these pesudo-random looking numbers.

If you are using c++11 or newer, consider using #include  / mt19937 random number generator which is MUCH better than rand()/srand()

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(1.0, 10.0);

for (int i=0; i<16; ++i)
    std::cout << dist(mt) << "\n";
```